# phpMyAdmin SSL защита MariaDB (Amazon AWS Linux2 LAMP server)

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, ssl, amazon-web-services

Я особо не разбираюсь в networking-е. Я создал сервер на Amazon AWS на основе Amazon Linux2, установил на него LAMP, подсоединил к нему Elactic IP, который соединил со своим доменом, и установил Let's Encrypt Certbot-а. Затем установил phpMyAdmin, чтобы подсоединяться к MariaDB. 
Решил создать сервер и датабазу, прежде чем учить PHP и работу с датабазами. Не планирую особо углубляться. С терминалом тоже не особо умею работать. Цель - соединить своё приложение в Unity с датабазой. Но столкнулся с некоторыми трудностями:
Я создал файл cofig.inc.php на основе файла config.sample.inc.php в папке phpMyAdmin. Там я только добавил blowfish_secret. При входе в phpMyAdmin у меня на сайте, всё нормально открылось. Меня только попросили созать автоматически датабазу phpmyadmin. На сайте у меня HTTPS соединение, но в phpMyAdmin написано во вкладке Database server в пункте Server connection: SSL is not being used.
Я только примерно представляю как функцианирует SSL защита. Я не уверен, достаточно ли того, что браузер показывает, что у меня HTTPS соединение с phpMyAdmin, т.к. phpMyAdmin показывает обратное. Ещё я не уверен, что правильно отредактировал файл cofig.inc.php. Возможно мне надо было добавить комманды типа $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'], но т.к. не понимаю как Certbot работает, я не представляю с какими файлами мне надо было бы их связывать (key, pem...) и где они находятся. И что ещё желательно/надо добавить в файл cofig.inc.php?
Ещё, хотелось бы знать, защищены ли таким образом все посылаемые и принимаемые данные. Допустим в Unity я отправлю форму на https://example.com/index.php а index.php заполнит датабазу. Или мне надо добавлять ещё какую-то защиту?
Спасибо.
Документация, которую я использовал:
[Tutorial: Install a LAMP Web Server on Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html)
[Appendix: Let's Encrypt with Certbot on Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#letsencrypt)
[Configuring phpMyAdmin: Manually creating the file](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file)

Comment: У вас ДВА соединения: одно между вами и phpMyAdmin, другое - между phpMyAdmin и MariaDB. Вот на одном из них (угадайте каком) SSL есть, а на другом нету

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за ответ. Он помог мне двигаться в верном направлении.

Comment: @andreymal, а мне вообще нужно настраивать SSL для phpMyAdmin - MariaDB связи, если база данных находится на том же сервере?

Comment: Скорее всего нет